# get value from <select> and write output

Tags: javascript

I want to use the value from 'standings' to determine what is printed out in 'leaderboard'  I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.  I think this is the closest I have come to getting it to work.  How can I pass the local variable team from inside the function to 'leaderboard'?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http-//www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jose Cuervo PBV</title>
        <link href="rosters.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var teams = new array(5);
                teams[0] = "Jenny Kropp         Whitney Pavlik";
                teams[1] = "Jennifer Fopma      Brooke Sweat";
                teams[2] = "Kristen Batt        Raquel Ferreira";
                teams[3] = "Emily Day           Heather Hughes";
                teams[4] = "Christal Engle      Tealle Hunkus";

                function listTeam(sel) {
                    var i = document.getElementById('standings').value;
                    var team = teams[i];
                }
</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src = "./images/Cuervo_Logo.jpg" alt = "Cuervo PBV Logo" />
        <select id='standings' name='standings' onchange="listTeam(this)">
            <option value='0'>First Place</option>
            <option value='1'>Second Place</option>
            <option value='2'>Third Place</option>
            <option value='3'>Fourth Place</option>
            <option value='4'>Fifth Place</option>
        </select>

        <select id='leaderBoard' name='leaderBoard' multiple="multiple" size="1" style="width: 300px;" >
            <option>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write(team);
                </script>
            </option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your whole approach here probably won't work. `document.write()` will only get called once when the page is first processed. (`document.write()` is in general not very useful anymore.) That is, changing the selected value in `standings` won't change `leaderBoard`. You should change this so `listTeam()` uses DOM manipulation to change the content of the `leaderBoard` element. (A straightforward way to do this is using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML))

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to put your results inside the option element you could just do a innerHTML inside the function you are using. So this would look like the following:

```
  function listTeam(sel) {
     var i = document.getElementById('standings').value;
     var team = teams[i];

     document.getElementById('leaderBoardOptions').innerHTML = team;

  }
```

And off course put an id on the option element.

`<option id="leaderBoardOptions"></option>`

also check out [this](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) site it has some nice explanation about using innerHTML

Comment: Just to expand on the answer a little. Whenever you include a `<script>` tag, the browser will run that code as soon as it loads that part of the page. In this case, the leaderBoard's option tag executes the `doc.write()` right away. I'm guessing you want to wait to do that until they've selected something. Think of all your HTML as providing a structure and placeholders for information, then when something changes or the user provides input, your JavaScript functions will change the information in the HTML placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http-//www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>Jose Cuervo PBV</title>
        <link href="rosters.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <img src = "./images/Cuervo_Logo.jpg" alt = "Cuervo PBV Logo" />
    <select id='standings' name='standings' onchange="listTeam(this)">
        <option value='0'>First Place</option>
        <option value='1'>Second Place</option>
        <option value='2'>Third Place</option>
        <option value='3'>Fourth Place</option>
        <option value='4'>Fifth Place</option>
    </select>
    <select id='leaderBoard' name='leaderBoard' multiple="multiple" size="1" style="width: 300px;" ></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //put script block at end of body to ensure all other elements have already
        //been loaded into the DOM (and therefore exist when we need them to.
        //
        //"new Array" is not helpful here, so use literal notation instead.
        var teams = [
                "Jenny Kropp         Whitney Pavlik",
                "Jennifer Fopma      Brooke Sweat",
                "Kristen Batt        Raquel Ferreira",
                "Emily Day           Heather Hughes",
                "Christal Engle      Tealle Hunkus"
            ],
            listTeam = function listTeam(sel) {
                var val = document.getElementById('standings').value, //get the selected value
                    team = teams[val],  //get the selected team, based on value
                    opt = document.createElement('option'), //create an <option> element
                    lb = document.getElementById('leaderBoard'), //get the leaderBoard select element
                    children = lb.children.length, //store the number of <option> child elements
                    child = null, //declare a variable to store an <option> child element
                    i = 0; //incrementor
                opt.innerText = team; //set the innerText
                for (i = 0; i < children; i += 1) {
                    //loop through every child element of leaderBoard
                    child = lb.children[0]; //store reference to element
                    lb.removeChild(child); //remove from leaderBoard
                }
                lb.appendChild(opt); //add new <option> element 
            };
        listTeam(); //call function on initial load as the leaderBoard select element has a selected child
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```